# C# button performclick not working when used Task method with socket

Tags: c#, winforms, websocket, .net-7.0

Socket closed event retry function.
(Socket Class)

```
private static async Task RetryConnect()
{
    Main main = new();

    int retries = 0;
    while (!clientConnected && retries < 4) // Time: 20s
    {
        main.Logger("Info", "WebSocket client not connected. Retrying in 5 seconds...", false);
        var t = Task.Delay(5000);
        t.Wait();
        retries++;
    }

    if (!clientConnected)
    {
        main.Logger("Info", "WebSocket client did not reconnect within 15 seconds. Starting up Application process...", false);

        main.Start_btn.PerformClick();
    }
    else
    {
        main.Logger("Info", "WebSocket client reconnected successfully.", false);
    }
}
```

Button function: (Main Class)

```
private async void Start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Settings.HAENABLE)
    {
        SocketServer_cbox.Checked = false;
        SocketClient_cbox.Checked = true;
        SocketServer_cbox.Enabled = false;
        SocketClient_cbox.Enabled = false;
        Logger("Info", "HA Service Starting Up...", false);
    }
    else
    {
        Logger("Info", "HA Service Disabled.", false);
    }
        

    await StartAllProcess("CHG_ACC_RANDOM", 0);
}
```

If socket not connected withing 20s this button should need be trigger but it's not working (and no errors or warnings). `Start_btn.PerformClick()` working inside of the main class.

- These 2 classes in 2 different files and I need to trigger the button when socket client not re-connected withing 20s.

Comment: Do not use `.Wait()`. `await` the delay. This may not solve your main problem, but it will solve one of your problems with this code.

Comment: Yes, I tried with `await` but it skips all the while process. But `Wait()` works well.

Comment: No it doesn't actually, you just don't know,  yet.

Comment: @Fildor Can you tell me how. Is this correct `await Task.Delay(5000);` ?